# NetSuite:Company CAD Invoice form and Company Inc Invoice form

Tags: netsuite

Can someone help me in the below issue that we are having please: Can this be done through a workflow rule, if yes how? I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Company CAD Invoice form and Company Inc Invoice form - we want to use the Company CAD invoice form when we are invoicing a customer in the Canada Subsidiary and the Company Inc Invoice form when we are invoice a customer in the Company Inc Subsidiary. Right now the CAD invoice is linked to the employee role labeled "Company - senior accountant," but this causes issues when someone assigned that role needs to invoice something for Company Inc

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is definitely possible. There are several ways to do this, however, I would do this via a Client Side script with a pageInit and a postSourcing script.

If you choose invoice from the customer record, it will hit the pageInit script.
If you create an invoice from scratch, after you enter the customer, it will hit the postSourcing script.

Script should:

1. Check the subsidiary
2. Check the current Form
3. If the form for the subsidiary isn't correct
4. Change the form to correct form.

SEE CODE BELOW.  Hope that helps. Might be a few bugs to iron out, but you should get the gist.

```
function pageInit(type){
    var customer = nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'); 
    if(customer!='' && customer!=null){  // Check if customer is populated first
        var subsidiary = nlapiGetFieldValue('subsidiary'); // get subsidiary
        var form = nlapiGetFieldValue('customform'); // get form
        if(subsidiary == XX && form != YY){ // compare subsid id with form id - change XX and YY appropriately
            nlapiSetFieldValue('customform', YY)  // Set to the correct form.
        }
        // Add other if statements here
    }
}


function onPostSourcing(type, name) {
    if(name=='entity'){  // if customer is changed
        if(customer!='' && customer!=null){ // make sure user hasn't set customer to empty
            var subsidiary = nlapiGetFieldValue('subsidiary'); // get subsidiary
            var form = nlapiGetFieldValue('customform'); // get form
            if(subsidiary == XX && form != YY){ // compare subsid id with form id - change XX and YY appropriately
                nlapiSetFieldValue('customform', YY)  // Set to the correct form.
            }
            // Add other if statements here
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you Lez. I appreciate your reply. I am new to scripting and it will be a bit hard for me to do the above. Can it be done through a workflow? do you have any sample script you can share with me? Thanks again

Comment: I've added in the code above.  You could do it via a workflow I'm sure.  But I'm not strong with Workflows.  Prefer code as I have full flexibility and don't need to deal with a clunky UI.

Comment: Thanks Lez. I will try it out. Do you mind telling me how does it work with the code. I am new to all this. Where do i apply it on NetSuite?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can be done through a workflow but I've used code like the following a number of times to manage selecting the correct form. The Netsuite documentation for creating a User Event script is adequate.

```
function beforeLoad(type, myForm, req) {
    if ((type == 'edit' || type == 'create') && 'userinterface' == nlapiGetContext().getExecutionContext()) {
        var needFormId = doFormLookup();// whatever custom logic you have
        if (req && !req.getParameter('cf') && needFormId != nlapiGetFieldValue('customform')) {//avoid unnecessary redirect and redirect loops
            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'sHould redirect to form '+ needFormId);
            nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId(), (type == 'edit'), { cf: needFormId });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bknights. But how do i apply this code? Thanks again

Comment: This would be in a user event script. You upload the code to the SuiteScripts folder. Then go to customization; scripting; scripts; new. Then create a User Event Script. You need to be able to code the form logic you require so if you have no Javascript experience this may not be for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have employees with different roles such that there is a specific role for a specific subsidiary you can assign default form for each role.

Client script as suggested by @lez-yeoh is also good, I would recommend in addition, you write a user event script so, that if the entry point for record creation is other than user interface eg: - csv import, suitescripts, etc. it is guaranteed that correct form is chosen.

Comment: Thank you prasun. Your first suggestion wont work we will need a script as @lez mentioned. I was telling him I am new to scripting and it will be a bit hard for me to do the above. Can it be done through a workflow? do you have any sample script you can share with me? Thanks again